# Questions icons wrapping when title contains an extremely long word

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

The mobile site's Questions votes and answers icons wrap if a question title contains an extremely long word.

[image: Questions long title word causes icons to wrap]

Comment: Keep the Germans off SO :)

Comment: Thank God, the users of the app don't have hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobia

Comment: Saying a word that long could give you *pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis* (if you said it over an active volcano).

Comment: I wonder if the fix for this will be shortening the title length restriction...